# Facebook SDK remain logged in as specific user

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have a website where I need to pull all photos where I am tagged with my partner. This requires extended access permissions from both users. I have managed to get this to work but it requires me to login to Facebook as myself each time the access permissions expire.

What I need to do is grant my app these extended access permissions ***indefinitely*** so that I do not need to log in to Facebook to see the photos.

Basically I would like any random visitors to my website to see photos of myself and my partner [from Facebook] without having to log into Facebook.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Sounds like your app is using your access token and not one in the context of the visitor to your website. You can get some of, but not exactly, what you described by making the photos publicly shared in FB and using any access token (for each visitor of your website).

Comment: Thanks for your response but this isn't what I'm trying to achieve.

I want the website to stay logged in to Facebook as me.

With access to my profile it can then request my partners' photos and pull pictures of us together.

However I can't seem to stay logged in as myself. Any ideas much appreciated?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think all that is possible with how the api works today. The best you can do is get a long-lived access token and refresh it once every 60 days.